# Ошибка при формировании предсказания модели: PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Пытаюсь сформировать предсказание модели, предварительно обработав изображение.

Код предобработки:

```
tf.keras.preprocessing.image.load_img(
    'C:/Users/123/Desktop/apple_tree_classification/test/', grayscale=False, color_mode="rgb", target_size=(300, 300), interpolation="nearest"
)

image = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.load_img('C:/Users/123/Desktop/apple_tree_classification/test/')
input_arr = keras.preprocessing.image.img_to_array(image)
input_arr = np.array([input_arr])  # Convert single image to a batch.
predictions = model.predict(input_arr)
```

При запуске получаю следующую ошибку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можно решить данную проблему?

Answer (score 2):

Функция [tf.keras.preprocessing.image.load_img()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/load_img) ожидает в качестве первого аргумента путь к **файлу с изображением**. Вы же передали в качестве параметра **директорию** вместо пути к **файлу** с изображением.